# Неверный вывод из БД

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

Надо делать вывод данный из БД по номеру ид. Но вместо данных получаю имена столбцов. А запрос по моему правильно. Вот он:

```
cursor =  mSqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("select `site_name`,`login` from "+ DatabaseHelper.DATABASE_TABLE+" WHERE `_id` = "+nomrecik, null);
    String[] headers = new String[] {DatabaseHelper.SITE_NAME_COLUMN, DatabaseHelper.LOGIN_COLUMN,DatabaseHelper.PASSWORD_COLUMN};
```

Для тестировании решил вывести данные сначала на текстовые поля вот так:

```
website.setText(headers[0]);
login.setText(headers[1]);
```

Все вместе:

```
cursor =  mSqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("select `site_name`,`login` from "+ DatabaseHelper.DATABASE_TABLE+" WHERE `_id` = "+nomrecik, null);
String[] headers = new String[] {DatabaseHelper.SITE_NAME_COLUMN, DatabaseHelper.LOGIN_COLUMN,DatabaseHelper.PASSWORD_COLUMN};

    website.setText(headers[0]);
    login.setText(headers[1]);
```

Выводит только имена столбцов которые есть на запросе: `site_name` и `login`

Comment: Гм. Вы создали массив из трех строковых констант (`DatabaseHelper` же ваш класс?) и вывели первые два элемента этого массива в текстовые поля. БД вообще в процессе не поучаствовала.

Comment: Сначала сделал запрос курсором потом вывел эти данные на массив и после на поля. как это не поучаствовала?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы, вероятно, получаете имена столбцов из-за вот этой строки:

```
String[] headers = new String[] {DatabaseHelper.SITE_NAME_COLUMN, DatabaseHelper.LOGIN_COLUMN,DatabaseHelper.PASSWORD_COLUMN};
```

Вы создаёте массив со строками куда помещаете наименование колонок, а потом выводите их. А нужно получать данные из результата запроса (используя cursor).

Пример:

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
String item_content = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.LOGIN_COLUMN));

login.setText(item_content);
```

Comment: С функцией moveToFirst() и moveToNext() ?

Comment: @Red Shaman Именно. Сначала moveToFirst(), затем cursor.getString(#индекс столбца) для получения контента (getString - если в столбце содежится строковый тип).

Comment: может без всяких танцов `cursor.getString(#индекс столбца)` использовать? работать не будет?

Comment: @Red Shaman, нужно обязательно перейти к первой строке с помощью moveToFirst(). Иначе не сможет определить какую именно строку вы хотите получить. Я добавил пример в ответ.

Comment: Спасибо исправил работает.